# FLASK_WTF how does a newly initialized form variable have the data?

Tags: python, flask

I have a small flask web application.
All it does is:

```py
@app.route('/users', methods=["GET","POST"])
def create_user():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template(
        'user.html',
        form=form,
        name=name
    )
```

On the html side, I have:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form, action="/users") }}
</div>
{% endblock page_content %}
```

Surprisingly, the above view works. I don't understand how does the line `form = NameForm()` that should create a *new* form object, creates a form object that is already filled out. How does the `__init__` method of `NameForm` get the data? does it have access to current `flask.request`?

And is that a valid design pattern in flask or should I write two separate views to handle GET and POST requests?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It sounds  like it's working exactly as intended.

Comment: @KenKinder  Updated/Reworded the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a WTForms form, you can pass it the initial form data. Eg,

```py
form = NameForm(request.form)
```

That may be more what you're expecting. You're creating a form and you're passing it a request object to populate the form with. However, with Flask-WTF, that step is optional. If you do not pass a form any initial data, it will by default populate itself with the request data.

That makes it convenient to write forms like so:

```
def controller(...):
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():   # Form is both submitted and valid
        (do something)
    else:
        return render_template('view.html', form=form)
```

Now in your view.html, if the form did not validate, the user can correct any errors without having to retype anything because the form is already populated.

It's essentially a convenience thing.

Answer (score 0):

what you are missing is return inside the validate if statement:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=["GET","POST"])
def create_user():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for("create_user"))
    return render_template(
        'user.html',
        form=form,
        name=name
    )
```

Redirect to the right url_for in your example